# I am looking for a word that describes having a hunch that a bad event has happened before having any evidence of it

Tags: single-word-requests

Kinda like if you were to wake up and just know that something is wrong, the only thing I can think of is maybe "Avant vu" which means (directly translated) "Before seen" and is a word like deja vu but other than that I can't think of anything.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Please provide a sample sentence to demonstrate usage of the word as per instructions on the tag SWR: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word."

Comment: And while we wait, premonition

Comment: I think @Unrelated has nailed it.

Comment: Or foreboding, portent, apprehension, intuition, trepidation, precognition, prediction, prognostication.

Comment: I have a gut feeling?

Comment: I think premonition and presentiment refer to things that haven't happened yet.  I guess in books I've seen this described with a whole phrase, e.g. "I woke up Wednesday morning with a distinct feeling that something had changed, and not for the better."

Comment: As @HotLicks suggested: *foreboding*.

Comment: Let's see... a ***hunch***?

Comment: Hmm.. I understand what you're looking for and I think it's too specific to describe in one word as the protagonist of my novel suffered the same feeling..+1 for that. I agree with @aparente001 with the use of those words and the phrase provided seems to cover your request.. It will indeed be very helpful if you can provide an example where you need to fit the word..

Answer (score 0):

**ESP** (aka extrasensory perception) according to Wikipedia involves "reception of information not gained through the recognized physical senses but sensed with the mind."

It's similar to the "sixth sense" but sixth sense is often used to describe a heightened awareness of a person's immediate surroundings whereas ESP is has been used to describe a phenomena where someone knows something they should have no way of knowing. For example,

"My boss brought in donuts today which seemed odd, my sixth sense told me something was wrong."

"Through ESP I felt my grandmother had become ill and later learned she passed away."

Answer (score 0):

"Premonition" might work.  Or a "sense of foreboding"

Answer (score 0):

**Foresight**. :  an act or the power of foreseeing :  prescience  (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foresight)

It is just me or does "premonition" conjur visions of witches and warlocks?